# How can I access register variable in one role in another different play role in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
- name: mytask1
   hosts: "{{app_name | upper}}_{{ env | upper }}_myhost1"
   vars_files:
    - "envs/{{ env|lower }}/{{app_name|lower}}_{{env|lower}}_hc.yml"
   serial: 1
   gather_facts: False
   roles:
   - role: my-task1
```

this is my 1st play

in *my-task1/tasks/main.yaml*

```
 - name: mytask1 in role
    shell: sometask
    with_items: "{{ path.stdout_lines }}"
    register: task_status
```

in the same playBook i have another 2 play

Below is the 3rd play in the playbook

```
 - name: mytask2
   hosts: "{{app_name | upper}}_{{ env | upper }}_myhost1"
   remote_user: "{{ tom_user }}"
   vars_files:
    - "envs/{{ env|lower }}/{{app_name|lower}}_{{env|lower}}_hc.yml"
   serial: 1
   gather_facts: False
   roles:
   - role: my-task2
```

I want to use the task_status variable in my my-task2 like

*my-task2/tasks/main.yaml*

```
  - name: do some activity
    command: "sh {{ item.stdout }}/task.sh"
    with_items: "{{ task_status .results }}"
    when: item.stdout != ""
```

I m getting below error now when i m trying to use this as mentioned

**fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'results'"
}**

can i use the registred variable **task_status**  in my second play ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to simply use/debug `task_status` ? Because since your don't have a loop on the task where your register it, I seriously doubt it contains a `results` key (as clearly reported by your error message).

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator 
it do have loop i missed to put .

Comment: I also tried debug in both the roles 
in the ```- role: my-task1``` i got the correct output but in ```- role: my-task2``` i didnt got the expected outptut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Can I use the registred variable task_status in my second play ?**"*

A: Yes. You can if you use this variable for this purpose only. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: "echo {{ item }}"
      loop: [1, 2, 3]
      register: task_status

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ task_status.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - '1'
  - '2'
  - '3'
```

Such variables live in the *hostvars*. You can use variables from other hosts too, for example

```yaml
- hosts: host_A
  tasks:
    - command: "echo {{ item }}"
      loop: [1, 2, 3]
      register: task_status

- hosts: host_B
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars.host_A.task_status.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_B] => 
  msg:
  - '1'
  - '2'
  - '3'
```